# Broadcom tags probably need a once over, help?

Tags: discussion

This is more of a call for help but we have a bunch of duplicates and stuff in [broadcom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/broadcom).

Our most popular questions "feel" correct to me but you can never tell with these cards. I don't own any of this gear so I can't really try/test these but we can probably save ourselves a bunch of headache by checking them against 12.04 now and making sure we're up to date.

Also I am unsure if we need to split them into individual model numbers of cards or generalized them for clumps of related ones.

Any takers?

Comment: Still looking for help with this?

Comment: I think it wouldn't hurt for 12.04.