# What is wrong with the command-line tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A user is removing [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) tags from posts.

I'm a user who depends upon favorite tags to answer questions, and command-line is one of them. If the tag gets removed, I miss questions that I may answer. I don't find any problem with the tag, as is in the case of [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) tag.

So why is the user removing these tags?

was there any meta post where the users(majority) decided to remove the posts? If yes, give me the link so I could down vote it.

Comment: All I know of was this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8924/when-should-i-use-the-command-line-tag/

Comment: @Seth Then based on [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8925/184942), [this comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8924/when-should-i-use-the-command-line-tag/#comment17132_8926) and [this comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8924/when-should-i-use-the-command-line-tag/#comment17150_8926), **I think I should rollback the edits. What do you say as a moderator?** I can even write a detailed answer explaining why I think I should rollback the edits.

Comment: Please, add an answer :)

Comment: @Seth I wrote my answer.

Comment: I would recommend that you remove references to a specific user in your post; discussing a specific individual is rarely productive, and discussing the *actions* instead almost always leads to better results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Although there maybe hundreds of users of AU, only a few(50 to 100) actually visit meta.AU and even fewer actively participate here. So I am assuming that all other users of AU do not want there say in the site decisions and therefore **what the active meta users decide can be safely considered de-facto rule/behavior-recommendation for all users**.</sup>

---

Now [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8925/184942) on the question [When should I use the command-line tag?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8924/184942) says

> > The tag is applicable to **any and all questions** where the OP has specified that they **want a CLI and not a GUI solution**.
>
> and
>
> > **I don't care what else it(the question) is about**, if it is asking for a solution that is run from the terminal, it can be tagged as [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line).

This is supported by 20 users(upvotes+1) which is enough majority of the meta users.

[Another answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9011/184942) on the same question says

> > **I prefer a tag too much, rather than one too little**. Better too much information, than too little.
>
> and
>
> > **Editing tags out that are not wrong, is vandalism**.

This is supported by 7 users, which maynot be very good, but isn't bad either.

A [comment by a user](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8924/when-should-i-use-the-command-line-tag/8925#comment17132_8926) says the same in other words.

> > **More tags is always better than fewer tags**. That is [clearly stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/203101) in the tagging guidelines and it also makes sense.

and has got enough support.

Based on above posts, **I may say that what's going on is wrong**.

---

Now to support my decision to rollback the edits(and to advice others to do so as well), this is what I have to say

There are only two solutions available on this issue, either edit the post or rollback the edit. **As the edit is wrong and reediting the post to add just a single tag would be a minor edit, I recommend to rollback the edit** as it would be appropriate.