# Tag Synonym Request: Asus-Related Stuff

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Recently, Asus tags have been getting created left and right. I'd like to propose the following synonyms:

- [asus-pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-pc) -> [asus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus)
- [asus-laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-laptop) -> [asus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus)

The ASUS tag seems good enough to cover almost any question that requires ASUS (which honestly, shouldn't be many at all).

I am unable to submit this request myself as I do not have enough votes in either.

Comment: Yes to this, edit queue has been full of retags of these.

Comment: Synonyms created, and retags completed.

Comment: Due to the dispute, I have opened a community discussion thread on the topic for community members to voice opinions.  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16006/tag-separation-and-handling-the-asus-tag-and-separating-it-out-into-subcategori

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requested synonyms have been created.  It makes sense that [asus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus) is the master tag here; they're all just subcategories under that primary tag, so merging made sense.

All questions tagged with [asus-pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-pc) or [asus-laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-laptop) have been retagged with [asus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus) and the synonyms created.

---

**Justification**:

The thread linked to by Masi to is that of Super User, but also makes sense specifically for Logitech (example provided in there) in which many different products other than computers are made by Logitech.  Asus makes computers, and maybe some mobile phones.  Perusing through the tag briefly, only Asus computers (Laptops and PC towers) are being asked about here.

Perusing through the Asus tag, and the history of the two tags that were removed, the questions are about Asus PCs or Asus Laptops, which can fall under the same category, while an overwhelming majority of the [asus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus) tag covers exactly the same content.  Looking at the overlap here, all the Asus questions, including the previously-[asus-pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-pc) and [asus-laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-laptop) items fall under [asus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus).  While yes, Asus makes motherboards, graphics cards, etc., the majority of questions asked here are about the PC or laptops, and are not about the specific cards or other devices.  Unless there's overwhelming evidence these need split up (and I don't see it here), I believe the merge and synonyms are justified.

If the community wishes to reverse this, that's the Community's call, however we had only six questions in [asus-laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-laptop) and only one in [asus-pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asus-pc), which was the basis of the merge; as well, it appears that only one user was actually using these tags, and *only* during editing of existing questions to 'create' these tags.  Community members were rejecting the tag changes already, which was a further consideration point for the merge and synonym creation.

Comment: I disagree this merge action without more complete discussion with the community. It is against policies done in other Stackexchange network sites.  - - I think we can learn from them and improve the quality of threads in Askubuntu.

Comment: @Masi Unless these policies are on Meta.SE, other sites policies may differ somewhat from these policies.  If you think this needs global policy, then you should make a Meta.SE post.  As well, your link to "product tags" applies where one company produces many different product lines, like Logitech does, and does not necessarily apply to, say, Dell or Asus, which are primarily computer manufacturers.  Further, there's generally not much distinction between the laptop and PC specific split, as 99% of the Asus questions are about a mix of PC and Laptop, so separating makes little sense.

Comment: A reminder: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7733/25388 We do not need company and manufacturer tags. Your figures are not from this world. Apples and Bananas are not 99% of everything.

Comment: @Masi A rebuttal: the same answer on that same meta post can be used for your separation of the tags out - separating to asus-pc and asus-laptop is (1) providing circumstantial information that is ultimately not useful, and (2) important enough for the title or content to indicate the computer but ultimately not useful to have on their own as a tag.  Given that what you're doing adds two extra tags, and I see almost no references to **any other Asus product in the questions under the tag**, I believe the merge justified (as we now only have one tag, instead of two equally useless ones)

Comment: It is not argument what was bad before that we want to have that bad still. - - I think Askubuntu must improve. - - Too much bad quality content in threads involving tags like `asus`, `apple`, `microsoft`, ... There are too much Ubuntu-related bugs in many softwares and hardwares. - - The resolution times of those is too much. Those things are much easier to deal with if you have inclusions in tags too. Not all apples are Apple! - - Please, pay little more attention to the bugs related to Ubuntu's software in Asus products. Asus-laptop and Asus-pc are like bananas and apples, not all bananas.

Answer (score -2):

Only manufacturer and company tags are problematic, *specific products are not*, please read the answer [here](https://meta.superuser.com/a/8403/2005). Please, see the discussion of the similar issue in the thread *[Manufacturer & Company tags are back. Again](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8402/2005)*. 
I disagree Thomas' opinion because threads of `asus` tag are generally low in quality, similarly as `apple`/...; having much duplicate threads, copy-pasted exact answers from other threads, too few closed threads, ...

> Adding asus-laptop and asus-pc are no longer going to help, and removal of asus tags won't help either.

Common problem: you have separate tags as `laptop` + `asus` + ... / `logitech` + `mause` + ... / `logitech` + `server` + ... / ... which is unspecific and confusing

- quality of threads including unspecific tags `asus`, `apple`, ... is generally low, having much duplicate threads, very few closed threads, ...

Examples

- Some tags such as `intel-gpu` and `intel-graphics` can be under `intel`
- `asus-laptop` and `asus-pc` are specific and should not be under `asus`
- `logitech-mouse`, `logitech-keyboard`, ... should not be under `logitech`

Related: [Do we need brand and manufacturer tags?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7733/25388) No, but there are some exceptions etc nvidia, ...

Comment: The thread you have dug up is almost two years old. This site has gone through a lot of changes in the past two years, and it's likely that the older information from there is no longer relevant (as was decided by a mod in this case.

Comment: Ok, that is really confusing. They have a situation of having `laptop` + `asus-laptop` + `power` + `power-supply`, for instance. - - I think it is ok. - - I think it is worser to put everything under one big pocket, etc `asus`. I would include both `asus` and `asus-laptop`.

Comment: If that's a question on this site, please post a link and I'll clean it up

Comment: Not here, but there. - - I still think their system is better that they include inclusions of two things. - - They can be much more precise in their content.

Comment: @ThomasWard Asus produces a variety of systems where the architecture differs completely in different products. You lose a lot of information if you describe all asus products as Asus. This has lead to many duplicate threads there such that people cannot find useful information easily. The asus-pc architecture is much different from asus-laptop, for instance. - - Asus also makes great motherboards, once again the target is completely different. - - I think to have those inclusions would make easier to work and improve the content here, since there many Ubuntu bugs in Asus products now.

Comment: @Masi What is the point of `asus-laptop` when a question can have `asus` and `laptop` tags? It shows the same information right? With the added benefit of both tags being flexible for multi-use cases. This can be applied to `asus` anything. Your comments above, to me, refute your own point `laptop + asus-laptop + power + power-supply` just shows how pointless `asus-laptop` is, it is totally redundant in this case, as we have `asus` and `laptop`.

Comment: @MarkKirby No, it is not redundant because it shows inclusion of the two topics. If you have `asus` and `laptop` is not the same thing. The target here is to improve content here and improve resolution times. The current system does not lead to quality content. Now, much effort is lost in having much complications of the issue.

Comment: Could not disagree more, breaking the tags up is more confusing. You can have five tags on a question, there is just no need for `asus`, `laptop` and `asus-laptop` because it is covered by the first two, it in no way improves resolution times, it is totally redundant. "The current system does not lead to quality content" Prove to me how not having an `asus-laptop` tag will lead to low quality content, that is a completely fallacious strawman, not having a tag has NO EFFECT on peoples ability to write a good answer.

Comment: @MarkKirby I cannot more disagree with your comment's content. Estimate how much we have unspecific threads/... under those tags at the moment. - - Can you? -- About inclusions in the other thread http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16015/25388